# What is the lift support travel distance for Rav4 2013 non-power lift gate?

Tags: toyota, rav4

I'm trying to determine the overall length and travel distance for the non-power hatch lift cylinder support for 2013 Toyota Rav4 XLE; product code [689600R010](https://www.oemautopartsandaccessories.com/catalog/parts/view/n/lift-cylinder-689600r010/v/toyota-rav4-2013/vtec/402222/pid/467b22afe46d8e05/)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can usually find this type of information if you look at aftermarket part sites.

http://www.rockauto.com/en/moreinfo.php?pk=8435972&cc=3294225&jsn=411

Compressed length is 14.93
Extended length is 19.93

I will assume those measurements are inches. Those are the overall lengths and that makes the travel distance 5 inches.

Comment: Yup, you're right, I measured the actual lift support, and those lengths check out, thx.